# How to find the lowest common ancestor of two nodes in XQuery?

Tags: xquery, basex

Suppose the input XML is

```
<root>
<entry>
    <title>Test</title>
    <author>Me</author>
  </entry>
</root>
```

I would like to find the lowest common ancestor of `title` and `author`.
I tried the following code in BaseX:

```
 let $p := doc('t.xq')//title, 
 $q := doc('t.xq')//author, 
 $cla := ($p/ancestor-or-self::node() intersect $q/ancestor-or-self::node()) 
 return 
    $cla
```

But it returns nothing (blank output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works totally fine for me, apart from returning *all* common ancestors.

### The Last Common Ancestor

Since they're returned in document order and the last common ancestor must also be the last node, simply extend with a `[last()]` predicate.

```
declare context item := document {
  <root>
    <entry>
      <title>Test</title>
      <author>Me</author>
    </entry>
  </root>
};

let $p := //title, 
    $q := //author, 
    $cla := ($p/ancestor-or-self::node() intersect $q/ancestor-or-self::node())[last()]
return 
    $cla
```

### Files and Databases

If the query you posted does not return anything, you might be working on a file `t.xq`. `intersect` requires all nodes to be compared in the same database, each invocation of `doc(...)` on a *file* creates a new in-memory database. Either create a database in BaseX with the contents, or do something like

```
declare variable $doc := doc('t.xq');
```

and replace subsequent `doc(...)` calls by `$doc` (which now references a *single* in-memory database created for the file).

Comment: Thank you, please read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816530/2651073). I just replaced doc('t.xq') with $db and it works, you may have an explanation?!

Comment: No, I have no idea, works for me. What BaseX version are you using?

Comment: BaseX 8.2, did you test it with the external file 't.xq'?

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible way :

```
let $db := doc('t.xq'), 
$q := $db//*[.//title and .//author][not(.//*[.//title and .//author])]
return 
  $q
```

**brief explanation :**

- `[.//title and .//author]` : The first predicate take into account elements having descendant of both `title` and `author`.
- `[not(.//*[.//title and .//author])]` : Then the 2nd predicate applies the opposite criteria to the descendant elements, meaning that overall we only accept the inner-most elements matching the first predicate criteria.

**output :**

```
<entry>
  <title>Test</title>
  <author>Me</author>
</entry>
```

Comment: Thank you,  what is the problem with my solution?

Comment: see the explanation above. I'm not sure why yours fails, but AFAIK, even if it works, it will select all *common ancestors* (not only *the lowest common ancestors*)

Comment: As it is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816530/2651073 I introduced $db variable as you did, now it works, do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I changed `doc('t.xq')` in front of the variables `$p` and `$q` with the variable `$db` as follows. Now it works (plus, I used the `last()` to have the last (lowest) common ancestor).

```
let 
$db := doc('t.xq'),
$p := $db//title, 
$q := $db//author, 
$cla := ($p/ancestor-or-self::node() intersect $q/ancestor-or-self::node())[last()] 
return $cla
```